# Shortcut to get out of the parenthesis in R when calling a function

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts, workflow

Usually when I call a function in R my workflow is:

`|` here indicates the cursor:

1. Start typing function name until R makes suggestions: e.g. `libra`
2. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd>: resulting in the cursor between parenthesis: e.g.`library(|)`
3. Then I write the name and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>: e.g. `library(tidyv|`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`
4. And end here: `library(tidyverse|)`
5. Then I press right arrow and then I press space to get: `library(tidyverse)  |`

How can I get out of the parenthesis with a Shortcut:
to get here: `library(tidyverse)  |`

Ideally something in combination with the last <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: Are you using [tag:rstudio], Rterm, Rgui, or another IDE?

Comment: Sorry. Rstudio.

Comment: Thank you Henrik. Consider this: `mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(|)))`. Either with tab or enter we end within the parenthesis. To proceed we have to press right arrow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was only considering the example shown in your question.

Comment: According to [Keyboard Shortcuts in the RStudio IDE](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts), End would be an option in Windows & Linux.

Comment: Indeed the combination of `TAB`+`End` is working! So it should be possible to change `End` with another key? And please post as answer!

Comment: Not too hard to google: [Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in the RStudio IDE](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts). Feel free to answer. Cheers